# How to add a while loop to a variable to display and if - else if result?

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have a `if - else if`  statement changing the query from a db based on user input, and I'm displaying the respective results in while loop one for all the `if - else if` statements however how can I put the while loop into a variable such as $output then just echo that when the if conditions are met?

```
<?php include 'db_connect.php';

$job_title = $_POST['job_title'];
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$salary = $_POST['salary'];

if($job_title !== " "){ 
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE jobTitle LIKE :job_title");
 $sql->bindValue(':job_title', '%' . $job_title . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
 if($sql->execute()) {
       $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 

 // while loop here //

} else if($company_name !== " ") {
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE company_name LIKE :company_name");
  $sql->bindValue(':company_name', '%' . $company_name . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if($sql->execute()) {
       $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

  // while loop here //

}else if($salary !== " ") {
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE salary_info LIKE :salary");
  $sql->bindValue(':salary', '%' . $salary . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if($sql->execute()) {
       $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

  // while loop here //    

  } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the entire query result in a variable using [**PDOStatement::fetchAll**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Later you use the query result outside of `if-else` block as per your requirement.

```
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';

    $job_title = $_POST['job_title'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $salary = $_POST['salary'];

    $output = "";
    if($job_title !== " "){ 
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE jobTitle LIKE :job_title");
        $sql->bindValue(':job_title', '%' . $job_title . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($sql->execute()){
            $output = $sql->fetchAll();
        } 
    } else if($company_name !== " ") {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE company_name LIKE :company_name");
        $sql->bindValue(':company_name', '%' . $company_name . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($sql->execute()) {
            $output = $sql->fetchAll();
        }
    }else if($salary !== " ") {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE salary_info LIKE :salary");
        $sql->bindValue(':salary', '%' . $salary . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($sql->execute()) {
           $output = $sql->fetchAll();
        }
    } 

    // Now you can use that query result `$output` as per your requirement.
?>
```

Also, I changed the datatypes in `->bindValue()` methods, and that's because I'm assuming *jobTitle* and *company_name* are of string datatype whereas *salary* is of integer type. If that's not the case then you need to change the datatypes in `->bindValue()` methods accordingly.

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the entire query result structure, do `var_dump($output);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the while loop just once after all the if-else statement has ended.